# JLayer still playing MP3 after closing app

Tags: java, swing

I have used `JLayer` as an API to play automatically a sound file called `login.mp3` when the main frame enabled. When I opened the frame, it worked quite perfectly. However, when I closed the frame, the music is still playing.

So how can I stop the music when closing the frame?

```
try {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(
            "resources" + File.separator + "audio" + File.separator + "login.mp3");
    Player playMP3 = new Player(file);
    playMP3.play();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: is your frame setted to close on exit? (frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE))

Comment: yes it is ! I've had that code

Comment: Please provide [mcve] so we can also reproduce your problem. Please also tell us which mp3 library you use.

Comment: Instead of setting `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, you should add a `WindowListener` to the frame. In the `windowClosing` method, you can call `playMP3.close();` to stop and close the player.

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions !